# Can AC and DC be converted and compared?

Tags: dc, ac

This is coming from an IT scenario;

An example server may have a power draw rating of 1.5A at 230V. When connected to a UPS and the mains power supply goes out, the UPS batteries are now providing DC power. Is there a way to calculate the DC draw of the server now, knowing its AC draw (I mean mathematically, not via server management tools)?

As another example to clarify, a router in a data centre is currently giving the following readout;

```
>show power
system power total =     2771.16 Watts (65.98 Amps @ 42V)
system power used =      1450.26 Watts (34.53 Amps @ 42V)
system power available = 1320.90 Watts (31.45 Amps @ 42V)
```

This is presumably using 34.53A at 42V, DC. Is a there a calculation or formulae to calculate how much power that is in AC power, and vice verse if a have an AC value to produce a DC value. Or, have I miss-understood and these two power values can not be compared in any way? Or, third option, should I compared their values in Watts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are so confused it's a little hard to tell exactly how.  Power is EMF (electromotive force) times current.  When the EMF is expressed in Volts and the current in amps, then the product of the two is power in Watts.

Your server is drawing 1.5 A at 230 V, which means it is using 345 W.  When the main power goes out and the UPS supplies power itself, this doesn't change since the server never sees a difference (that is after all the job of a UPS).  The server is still using 345 W.  Instead of those 345 W coming from the power line, they are now ultimately coming from the battery in the UPS.  There is a circuit, called a *inverter* in the UPS that converts the battery DC voltage to the AC voltage the server expects.  We know the server is using 345 W coming out of this inverter.  These things of course aren't perfect, so there is some loss in the inverter.  Let's say it is 90% efficient (pretty good but not unrealistically so).  That means the power going from the battery into the inverter is 345/90% = 383 W.  The difference of 38 W is lost as heat in the inverter.  If the battery is 48 V, then it is supplying 383 W / 48 V = 8.0 A.

Comment: Thanks Olin, yes I see now, watts is the way to go here. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The main way to convert AC into DC is using diodes.The best quality of diodes is their rectifying capabilities allouding the flow of current in only one direction.As you probable know AC is sinusoidal,this means that current goes in one direction in a half-cycle of the wave and the opossite direction in the other half cycle of the wave.There are several ways of converting AC into DC,one example is the **half wave rectifier**,in this case you place only one diode in your circuit,the problem here is that you will take advantage of the half of the voltage source,altough there is a better way of doing this by implementing a **full wave rectifier** with 4 diodes included.For a better understanding of this I fully recommend you to read about functioning principles of diodes and their applications.You can calculate the DC output by using High Signal Model or Low Signal Model(depending on the input) for diodes,this means to change the diode by common circuit elements so you can apply KLV and other classic methods to your circuit.Normally you place a DC source in series with a resistance when the diode is forward biased.